# Wish to hover over a container and have both elements (an Image) and p react and change at the same time

Tags: html, css

I have a `<button>` that is css formatted with a png as `background-image` and that has the `width` and `height` limited. Also a `<p>` with text. This is actually changing as expected On `:hover` but the button image is not. On `:hover` I have the css set to change the `background-position` to a different part of the larger image.

I  have picked up some code from other answers here on stack overflow and tried to make them fit what I need. I have actually tried for days to make this work and deleted a lot of code in the process. I created a jsfiddle to show what is working and what isn't. Sorry for probably asking the same thing as others. 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zrLa58f/1/)  Hope I did that right.

```css
  /*Testing buton and id add to basket  without the anchor . so far not working*/
  /* <!-- test of https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bENBGW --> */
  .frame {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: ##00F;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;  
  }

.frame:hover > .info > p{
    font-size: 14px;
    color:green;
}

.frame:hover > .button > img#add-to-basket1 { 
    background-position: 42px 0px;
} 
/* also tried 
.frame:hover > img#add-to-basket1 { background-position: 42px 0px;}  and
.frame:hover > #add-to-basket1 { background-position: 42px 0px;}
*/

.info {
    float: left;
    max-width: 220px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 42px;
}

.info p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #8F8F8F;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

img.button {
    border-radius: 100%;        
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url('https://ggeddes.com/_media/_media/Button1_6Square.png');

    height: 42px; width: 42px;
    background-size: 85px 250px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    line-height:42px;
    float: left;
}

#add-to-basket1 { background-position: 0px 0px;}
```

```html
  
    <div class="frame">
      <img class="button" id="add-to-basket1"/>
      <div class="info">
        <p>Preparing Your Home For Showing</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something Like This?

**Here is the problem:**

`.frame:hover > .button > img#add-to-basket1 { }`

This means that you are referencing `img#add-to-basket1` which is inside of `.button` based on your code. But `.button` and `img#add-to-basket1` refers to the same element. so you can remove either of them. in my case I just removed `.button`.

```css
/*Testing buton and id add to basket  without the anchor . so far not working*/
/* <!-- test of https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bENBGW --> */
.frame {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: ##00F;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;  
}

.frame:hover > .info > p{
    font-size: 14px;
    color:green;
}

.frame:hover > img#add-to-basket1 { 
    background-position: 42px 0px;
} 
/* also tried 
.frame:hover > img#add-to-basket1 { background-position: 42px 0px;}  and
.frame:hover > #add-to-basket1 { background-position: 42px 0px;}
*/

.info {
    float: left;
    max-width: 220px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 42px;
}

.info p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #8F8F8F;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

img.button {
    border-radius: 100%;        
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url('https://ggeddes.com/_media/_media/Button1_6Square.png');

    height: 42px; width: 42px;
    background-size: 85px 250px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    line-height:42px;
    float: left;
}

#add-to-basket1 { background-position: 0px 0px;}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <img class="button" id="add-to-basket1"/>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Preparing Your Home For Showing</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I thought I had tried all of the different classes and ids. Thank you so much.

Comment: I am Glad I was able to help @geddeca. Good luck!